# Some elementary problems in Group Theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Somebody can to give me a hint for the following problems?

> 1. Let $T$ be a cyclic normal subgroup of $G$. Prove that if  $\;U < T$, then $U\lhd G$.
> 2. Prove that if $p$ is prime, then $\mathrm{Aut} (\mathbb{Z}_p) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$.

The following problems I know how to do in the hard way, but I think that exists a more easy way that do this (even that use a big theorem in group theory, like that of classifications). Do you know?

> Determine the conjugacy class of the following groups:
>
> > (a) $G = \mathbb{Z}_5$;
> >
> > (b) $G = {S}_3$ (symmetric group);
> >
> > (c) $G ={D}_4 $ (dihedral group);
> >
> > (d) $G = Q_8$ (quaternion group);
> >
> > (e) $G = D_5$;

Thank you!

Comment: It would be better if the second problem set was posted separately. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Problem 1 as you have stated it says that if a group ($G$) has a cyclic normal subgroup ($T$), then all its subgroups ($U$) are normal. This is false.

Comment: In the very first question, is $U$ meant to have any relation to $T$? It's certainly not true as currently written. In the last bunch, do you mean, determine the conjugacy *classes*?

Comment: Also, do you know the theorem that says that the size of the conjugacy class of $x$ equals the index of the centralizer of $x$?

Comment: @Gerry (and Rob), this is a question of a text-book that I can't to solve. I write in the same way like in the book (I just have to translate, because the book is in portuguese). So, if this isn't true, do you can give me a counter-example?

While the theorem that you have mentioned, I know. Indeed, I have used it for to solve the question, but even so, this is so painful...

Comment: @Berci has edited your question so that instead of saying $U\lt G$ it says $U\lt T$. Is that edit correct?

Comment: Oh, yeah! That's it.

Comment: I'm going to have to downvote, as there are 7 questions in this one post, and not an ounce of work from the OP.

Comment: @Steve D, I don't ask for to solve. I only ask for hints. If you can't to help or don't want to help, don't disturb. Sometimes, a person don't get a question because he can't to do the firts step. Only the question 1 and 2 I have doubt. The others I put only for that somebody can to shared another solution different of that one trivial. One more time, don't disturb. Help us. Thanks.

Comment: You just copied multiple questions straight from your textbook, with no thoughts of your own.  That's why I downvoted.  I have no inclination to help you; I was simply leaving a comment, because it is the polite thing to do when downvoting.

Comment: Walner, how is anyone going to know whether she has a solution differing from yours, when you don't give any idea of what your solution is? Please don't be rude to @Steve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. If $U$ is a subgroup of a cyclic group $T=\{e,t,t^2,\dots,t^{n-1}\}$, then there is a $d\,|\,n$  such that $U=\{e,t^d,t^{2d},\dots\}$. Also use that $g^{-1}t^kg=(g^{-1}tg)^k$.
2. If $g\in Aut(\Bbb Z_p)$ then show that $g$ is uniquely determined by its value $g(1)$.

(a) $\Bbb Z_5$ is Abelian, so each conjugation $x\mapsto (-g)+x\,+g$ is the identity. 
(b) The unit element is always a separate conjugation class. For any $f\in S_n$, then verify that $f\circ(1\,2\,3\,...\,k)\circ f^{-1} = (f(1)\,f(2)\,...\,f(k))$ and conclude that two permutations are conjugate in $S_n$ iff they have the same cycle structure, hence $S_3$ has $3$ conjugacy classes. 
(c) $D_4=\{id,R,R^2,R^{-1},t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4\}$ where $R$ is the rotation by $+90^\circ$ and $t_i$'s are the reflections, in positive directed order. The center of $D_4$ is $\{id,R^2\}$, these form two private conjugation classes. For the rest, use that $R=t_1t_2=t_2t_3=t_3t_4=t_4t_1$. 
(d) $Q=\{1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k\}$. Its center is $\{1,-1\}$, yielding two conjugacy classes, and observe that $i^{-1}=-i$ and that $(-i)ji=-ki=-j$ so that $j\sim -j$. 
(e) $D_5$ doesn't contain the reflection on the origin (which was $R^2$ in the case of square).

Comment: Thanks, @Berci. Your hints indeed helped me.

Comment: What do you mean by *private* conjugation classes? (I've also seen *conjugacy* used rather than *conjugation*)